# How to convert map column to struct type with custom key-value names?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have a UDF that converts a Map (in this case String -> String) to an Array of Struct using the Scala built-in `toArray` function

```
val toArray = udf((vs: Map[String, String]) => vs.toArray)
```

The field names of structs are `_1` and `_2`.

How can I change the UDF definition such that field (key) name was "key" and value name "value" as part of the UDF definition?

```
[{"_1":"aKey","_2":"aValue"}]
```

to

```
[{"key":"aKey","value":"aValue"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a class:

```scala
case class KV(key:String, value: String)

val toArray = udf((vs: Map[String, String]) => vs.map { 
  case (k, v) => KV(k, v)
}.toArray )
```

Comment: Hi @user8098908 , The map itself can be null - will this throw a nullPointer exception?  Should there be a check for this perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.0+**

```
map_entries($"col_name")
```

This converts a map to an array of struct with struct field names `key` and `value`.

Example:

```scala
val df = Seq((Map("aKey"->"aValue", "bKey"->"bValue"))).toDF("col_name")

val df2 = df.withColumn("col_name", map_entries($"col_name"))

df2.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- col_name: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
//  |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

For custom field names, just `cast` a new column schema:

```scala
val new_schema = "array<struct<k2:string,v2:string>>"
val df2 = df.withColumn("col_name", map_entries($"col_name").cast(new_schema))

df2.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- col_name: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- k2: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- v2: string (nullable = true)
```